# How to work with size of the browser window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

```
var wh = $(document.documentElement.clientHeight).height();
var tH = $('.a_Top').height();
var bH = $('.a_BottomBar_b').height();
$('.a_ContentOuter').css('min-height',(wh)+'px');
$('.a_ContentInner').css('min-height',(wh-(tH+bH+29))+'px');
```

I am writing this code in a function but when i open this page in Firefox, it will be a error and when we comment on this whole code it will be fine, so please give me the suggestion and help to find out the right way to use this code ....

Comment: "_it will be a error_" - What error? Please post the error that you are getting.

Comment: `$(window).height()` should be used.

Comment: `document.documentElement.clientHeight` is a number, how to create a jQuery object of a number?

Comment: try `var wh = $(document.documentElement.clientHeight)[0]` or var `wh = $(window).height()`.

Answer (score 3):

Add  $(window).height();

```
var wh = $(window).height();
var tH = $('.a_Top').height();
var bH = $('.a_BottomBar_b').height();
$('.a_ContentOuter').css('min-height',(wh)+'px');
$('.a_ContentInner').css('min-height',(wh-(tH+bH+29))+'px');
alert($('.a_ContentOuter').css('min-height'));
```